# Regular expression for binary string containing no instances of 01

Tags: regular-languages, automata, regular-expressions

In order to enumerate such a regular expression, it's clear one can break down the language into the set $s =\{00,01,10,11\}$ and it is clear that we need to enumerate some expression that avoids the following combination of strings:
01, 00+10,00+11, 10+11. I'm just having finding trouble enumerating the regular expression to fulfill these following invariants.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a $0$, it may not be followed by a $1$, so the string is made of "not $0$s" followed by $0$s.

$$1^*0^*$$